# inserting in linked lists with ruby

Tags: ruby

Hi I'm trying to insert a value at a specific index in a linked list in ruby.

Here is my code thus far:

```
class Node
  attr_accessor :data, :pointer, :next

  def initialize(data, pointer = nil)
    @data = data
    @pointer = pointer
  end

  def next
    @data = @pointer
  end

end

class LinkedList
  attr_accessor :head, :data, :pointer

  def initialize(data)
    @head = Node.new(data, pointer)
  end

  def index_at(value_of_index)
    current = head
    value_of_index.times do 
      if current.pointer == nil
        current = Node.new(nil, nil)
        return current = current.data
      else
        current = current.next
      end
    end
    current.data
  end

  def insert_at_index(index, value)
    current = head
    index.times do
      current.next
    end
    current = Node.new(value)
  end
end
```

The problem I've having is with the def insert_at_index method... I can't seem to figure out how to place the new node at the index and value.  Any help you can give me would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Your `next` method seems to override `@data`. You probably just want to return `@pointer`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Say your linked list looks like this:

```
a -> b -> d -> e
```

To insert `c` into the 3rd index, you would move to the second index to get `b`, create a new node, set `b`'s next to the new node `c`, and set `c`'s next to the old third index item, `d`.

This will give you:

```
a -> b -> c -> d -> e
```

That said, the code should look like this:

```
def insert_at_index(index, value)
  current = head

  # make current b. You may want to put this in a function node_at_index
  (index - 1).times do
    raise "List not long enough" if current.nil?
    current = current.next
  end

  new_node = Node.new(value)     # new node c
  new_node.next = current.next   # c's next is b's next, d
  current.next = new_node        # b's next is c
end
```

From the looks of it there seem to be other issues with your code as well. You're overwriting `@data` in your next function (you probably meant to just `return @pointer`), `LinkedList#initialize` doesn't have `pointer` defined, etc

You could simplify your Node to look like this:

```
class Node
  attr_accessor :data, :next

  def initialize(data, next=nil)
    @data = data
    @next = next
  end
end
```

Which should work for you.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I changed my next method to def next
@pointer
end


I also implemented your changes above, but it still doesn't seem to be functioning properly...do you have any other suggestions?

Comment: I am getting the following error from the line: new_node.next = current.next. "new_node.next = current.next
NoMethodError: undefined method `next=' for #<Node:0x007f8be2c4c258 @data=10, @pointer=nil>"

Comment: finally got it, thanks for your help and thorough explanation!

Comment: @Becca I updated the answer to show a simpler version of Node which should fix that issue. Consider upvoting and accepting the answer if it was helpful!

Answer (score 0):

Here is one solution that worked for me:

```
class Node
  attr_accessor :data, :pointer
  alias_method :next, :pointer

  def initialize(data, pointer = nil)
    @data = data
    @pointer = pointer
  end

  def next
    @pointer
  end

end

class LinkedList
  attr_accessor :head, :data, :pointer

  def initialize(data)
    @head = Node.new(data, pointer)
  end

  def index_at(value_of_index)
    current = head
    value_of_index.times do 
      if current.pointer == nil
        current = Node.new(nil, nil)
        return current = current.data
      else
        current = current.next
      end
    end
    current.data
  end

  def insert_at_index(index, value)
    current = head

    (index - 1).times do
      if current.pointer != nil
      current = current.next
      end
    end
    new_node = Node.new(value)
    if current.pointer != nil
      new_node.pointer = current.pointer
    end
    current.pointer = new_node
  end

end
```